# Deep search within jsonb field PostgreSQL without knowking the key

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Assuming the following jsonb data :

```
{
    "3f210b": {
        "hash": "e60ab24c549ac7060fzedfefe563e8493d759bb"
    },
    "Siaa1b3": {
        "hash": "d24b37efgregr1a2c6db3b9334b3bf4fef3f22bfc9a43f"
    }
}
```

Is it possible, in PostgreSQL, to do a deep jsonb search without know the key (3f210b & Siaa1b3) but we know the hash.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? Do you always have only two levels?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 11, yes only two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Postgres 11 you will need to unnest that value:

```
select *
from the_table t
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_each(t.the_column) as x(ky, item)
              where x.item ->> 'hash' = 'd24b37efgregr1a2c6db3b9334b3bf4fef3f22bfc9a43f');
```

---

With Postgres 12, you could use the new JSON/Path expression:

```
select *
from the_table t
where jsonb_path_exists(the_column, '$.*.hash ? (@ == "d24b37efgregr1a2c6db3b9334b3bf4fef3f22bfc9a43f")')
```

Comment: Thank you ! Is that possible to return just the key value? In this case :
`"Siaa1b3": {
        "hash": "d24b37efgregr1a2c6db3b9334b3bf4fef3f22bfc9a43f"
    }`

Comment: EDIT : i end up with this one :

select value from the_tablecross join lateral jsonb_each(the_column) sub where  value @> '{"hash": "d24b37efgregr1a2c6db3b9334b3bf4fef3f22bfc9a43f"}';